# Non-Inverting op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image: Non inverting op amp circuit]

So, I am trying to understand the fundamentals of operational amplifiers for a project I am doing. I want to use a non-inverting op-amp circuit for a low frequency sound amplifier. I understand R1 and R2 is for biasing the op-amp to between VCC and ground. Also, the gain is set by 1+(R3/R4).

My question is whats the point of the C2, that's in parallel with R3, is? And how can I set the frequency band? would it be f = 1/2*pi*R*C?

And how do I start choosing component values? how do I decide which is the best for an application?

Comment: The gain is 1+(R3/R4) only if C2 isn’t conducting and C3 is fully conducting. At high frequencies C2 will conduct, reducing the effective R3 and hence the gain. At low frequencies C3 will stop conducting effectively increasing R4 and hence reducing gain. You don’t need C6 decoupler from ground to ground – that’s only needed if opamp negative rail is actually negative. At DC C3 doesn't conduct at all and the opamp becomes a unity gain buffer.

Comment: Although there are some technical errors in the writing (I think I may see one such on page 2), you might want to look over [this discussion from Linear Tech on unintended opamp oscillation](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an148fa.pdf). It's targeted at a modest audience level and, if it hits your sweet spot, may suggest some thoughts to consider with respect to those gain-setting resistors and associated capacitors tied to the (-) opamp input.

Comment: C2 is the compensation capacitor for stability.

Answer (score 9):

### Vin

Just to make sure you fully follow the overall approach, let's look first at the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGMANV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm sure you already know how to work out the Thevenin equivalent values for the right-hand side, above. But let's discuss \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ and \$C_1\$ for a moment.

\$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ may be any source arrangement. We usually take it be a single frequency for discussion purposes. (As it is possible to break up any arbitrary waveform into combinations of simpler single frequencies, there's no reason to do it differently.) And \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ may also have a DC offset, too. But whatever this DC offset may be, assuming \$C_1\$ is of a sufficiently large enough value, then \$C_1\$ will average out \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ and will acquire *exactly* the DC offset value. It takes a moment for this to happen, with a time constant of \$\tau_{_\text{IN}}=R_{_\text{TH}}\cdot C_1\$. But given enough time (say 5 or 6 \$\tau_{_\text{IN}}\$), the voltage across \$C_1\$ will be just the DC offset, itself. And there it will stay. In effect, \$C_1\$ then provides just enough added voltage to \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ so that its mean value at the (+) input of the opamp will be just \$V_{_\text{TH}}\$. It "jacks up" the input voltage so as to match up with your designed divider voltage value. Which is as it should be.

There's another small detail, and this is perhaps more important to be aware of with bipolar op amps: \$R_{_\text{TH}}\$ also provides the necessary bias current for the op amp. This bias current is usually as small as possible, but it is a necessary evil and there needs to be something that provides that bias. That *something* is \$R_{_\text{TH}}\$.

I want you to imagine what happens if there isn't such a resistor at the op amp (+) input. What happens??? Suppose you had either of the following two options, instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fet103.png)</sup>

Nothing good, I assure you. Nothing good, at all. You do *not* want the (+) op amp input being responsible for sourcing/sinking current to \$C_1\$. Unless you know a great deal more than is usual about the op amp, this kind of thing is a recipe for disaster.

So the following is your (+) input circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpWG0S.png)</sup>

You get to determine \$V_{_\text{TH}}\$ and \$R_{_\text{TH}}\$ and you need to make \$C_1\$ large enough so that it, together with \$R_{_\text{TH}}\$, thoroughly averages out the lowest frequency fluctuations you care about. In thinking about \$R_{_\text{TH}}\$, make sure it's small enough that the worst case op amp bias current doesn't generate an appreciable voltage drop across it.

One last thing. You don't show a source impedance in your schematic. But there always is one. Sometimes it is very low. Sometimes not. But it's something you need to at least think about. If it is very low, you can probably ignore it. But otherwise, you need to account for the fact that it forms a voltage divider with \$R_{_\text{TH}}\$, diminishing the signal amplitude, and it also means that \$C_1\$ takes a little longer still to establish its equilibrium voltage.

### Feedback

\$R_3\$ is pretty much how the op amp bias current gets supplied, here. The op amp output has to supply it through this resistor. You probably should consider setting \$R_3=R_{_\text{TH}}\$, so that the slight voltage drop (I said this drop should not be *appreciable*) is similar at the (-) and (+) inputs. It's not a strict requirement. But it's something to think about. And if you decide to go that way, then you've now already also determined \$R_3\$.

Nominally, \$R_4\$ is then how you set the voltage gain. But in reality, since this is more of a bandpass arrangement (though it does include a low-pass, as well), the band-pass gain is really:

$$A_v= 1 + \frac1{\frac{R_4}{R_3}+\frac{C_2}{C_3}}$$

Both the low-pass and band-pass frequency is:

$$\omega_{_\text{c}}=\frac1{\sqrt{R_3\,R_4\,C_2\,C_3}}$$

The unitless damping factor is:

$$\zeta=\frac12\,\omega_{_\text{c}}\left(R_3\,C_2+ R_4\,C_3\right)$$

where \$Q=\frac1{2\,\zeta}\$.

So, in setting all these values you have to decide what kind of 2nd order response you want to have.

For the band-pass, \$\omega_{_\text{L}}\,\omega_{_\text{H}}=\omega_{_\text{c}}^{\,2}\$, where:

$$\begin{align*}\left\{\begin{array}{l}\omega_{_\text{L}}=\omega_{_\text{c}}\left(\zeta-\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right)=\omega_{_\text{c}}\,\zeta\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac1{\zeta^2}}\right)\\\omega_{_\text{H}}=\omega_{_\text{c}}\left(\zeta+\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right)=\omega_{_\text{c}}\,\zeta\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac1{\zeta^2}}\right)\end{array}\right.\end{align*}$$

### A Design

So, let's say you want a wide band-pass behavior, spanning from \$f_{_\text{L}}=200\:\text{Hz}\$ to \$f_{_\text{H}}=15\:\text{kHz}\$ and that you want a pass-band gain of \$A_v\approx 10\$ for \$V_{_\text{in}}\approx \pm 250\:\text{mV}\$. Let's also say you have selected an op amp with a worst case bias current of \$2\:\mu\text{A}\$ (the [LT1800](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1800fa.pdf) qualifies) and that you've decided you want to keep the Thevenin voltage drop to below 5%, or \$12.5\:\text{mV}\$. So this suggests \$V_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{12.5\:\text{mV}}{2\:\mu\text{A}}=6.25\:\text{k}\Omega\$. This means that you could choose \$R_1=R_2=12\:\text{k}\Omega\$, with \$R_{_\text{TH}}=6\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Setting \$R_3=6.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$ would not be inconsistent with this.

So we can now compute \$R_4=\frac19\cdot R_3\approx 756\:\Omega\$. We can round this to \$R_4=750\:\Omega\$. Well, that's two resistors down. Two frequency-dependent capacitors to go.

Now find \$f_{_\text{c}}=\sqrt{200\:\text{Hz}\cdot 15\:\text{kHz}}\approx 1.732\:\text{kHz}\$ (\$\omega_{_\text{c}}=2\pi\sqrt{200\:\text{Hz}\cdot 15\:\text{kHz}}\approx 10.883\:\text{k}\frac{\text{Rad}}{\text{s}}\$.)

We should assume that \$C_2\$ is small compared to \$C_3\$. This makes a lot of sense, as \$C_3\$ should tend to ground \$R_4\$ at low frequencies and \$C_2\$ should tend to bypass \$R_3\$ at high frequencies. Let's make then a factor of 1000 apart. That's definitely enough of a factor to eliminate the capacitor term in the divisor of the second term in the \$A_v\$ equation.

We have two of the resistor values and we can re-arrange the equation for \$\omega_{_\text{C}}\$ above, applying also \$C_3=1000\cdot C_2\$, to then solve for \$C_3\$:

$$C_3=\sqrt{\frac{1000}{R_3 \cdot R_4\cdot  \omega_{_\text{c}}^{\,2}}}\approx 1.286\:\mu\text{F}$$

We can round that to \$C_3=1.2\:\mu\text{F}\$ and therefore \$C_2=1.2\:\text{nF}\$.

We find now that \$\zeta\approx 4.94\$, which is consistent with this band-pass design. (The fractional bandwidth is \$\frac{f_{_\text{H}}\:-\: f_{_\text{L}}}{f_{_\text{c}}}=\frac{15\:\text{kHz}\:-\: 200\:\text{Hz}}{1.732\:\text{Hz}}\approx 8.55\$.)

Here's the resulting simulation:

[image]

Using the LT1800 (rail to rail op amp), this isn't too far from the design expectations.

Yes, there is a process to follow. But it isn't overly complicated.

### Notes

Once thing to take note of, that didn't come out in various comments here so far, is that you can't just randomly pick your capacitor values on the basis of having \$C_3\$ be "arbitrarily very small." It might seem like that's okay, given some comments I read. But it's not okay.

The circuit will certainly work, for example, if you make \$C_3\$ (and \$C_2\$) both ten times larger. But its band-pass won't be the same, anymore. In this kind of arrangement, the values do matter. You don't get to just make \$C_3\$ arbitrarily big because it is "shorting low frequencies to ground." It is, kind of. But it matters exactly how much.

This then suggests that *sloppy* tolerances for your capacitors *also* matter in this circuit. You can't be sloppy with their values and then also expect to get a predicted behavior.

But you can be sloppy with your choice of the factor of 1000. You could just as well use 500 or 250 or 100, or 10000, I suppose. So, for example, if you find that getting precision \$1.2\:\mu\text{F}\$ capacitors is "hard to do" but that you can get \$680\:\text{nF}\$ more easily with good tolerances, then you could change the factor to 279.31 and this would give \$C_3=680\:\text{nF}\$. That makes \$C_2=2.435\:\text{nF}\$, which isn't so easy, but \$C_2=2.2\:\text{nF}\$ is near and would only impact the high end a little. That may be an acceptable compromise.

There is another compromise here, though. The unitless damping factor, \$\zeta\$, has been reduced to about 2.9. So the shape of the behavior within the band-pass is now also different.

Let's see by how much this difference in \$\zeta\$ makes:

[image]

The green line is the original design and the red line is the new, modified one. So choosing a capacitor ratio of 1000 or 279.31 does impact your results. It's also not as arbitrary as I made it seem, earlier. Details matter.

This gets to another consideration. You could instead approach this design by specifying a desired \$\zeta\$ and then determining the ratio of \$C_2\$ to \$C_3\$ based upon that choice, instead. In my case, I just double-checked the result and figured that "near 5" was good enough. But you can also see that there are various trade-offs.

The bottom line is that no matter which direction you choose to go (and you only have a few degrees of freedom available), verify your results both on paper and in simulation and make sure the results are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

C2 makes a low pass filter. Since you are amplifying audio, there is no point amplifying anything beyond audio or any signal you don't need, so it can be filtered out.

Set frequency band to what is your range of interest for audio. C3 just removes gain for DC and low frequencies.

The component values are decided by what impedances and what frequencies you want for the audio, then you can decide what balance you want for capacitors and resistors. The values can depend on which op-amp you intend to use. The values should not be too low to load down the circuit too much, but also not too high to add much noise.